# Qual a diferença semântica entre section e article?

Tags: html, html5, semântica

Pesquisando, encontrei algumas perguntas relacionadas as tags do HTML5:

- [Qual a diferença entre <div> e <section>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17246)
- [Como usar as tais tags semânticas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148753)
- [HTML5: diferença de section e article](http://www.kadunew.com/blog/html/html5-diferenca-de-section-e-article)
- [Documentação MDN sobre article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)
- [Documentação MDN sobre section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)

Porém ainda não consegui entender qual a diferença entre eles, nos diversos conteúdos que li, encontrei `article` dentro `section` e vice-versa, apenas `article` ou apenas `section`, `article` dentro de `article`, isso é um pouco confuso pra mim

Comment: Uma regra básica: se eu extrair esse elemento do seu contexto, ele continuará fazendo sentido? Se sim, tudo indica que é um `<article>`, se não, é possível que seja um `<section>`. Um capítulo de um livro, por exemplo, perderia o sentido, pois está fortemente associado ao contexto do resto da história - ele seria um `<section>`; já um post em um blog costuma ser independente de outros posts e fazer sentido mesmo fora do contexto do site - ele seria um `<article>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vou fazer minhas considerações sobre `<section>` e `<article>` baseada em algumas fontes de onde vou tirar parte do conteúdo.

**SECTION**

O elemento HTML `<section>` representa uma seção genérica contida em um documento HTML, geralmente com um título, quando não existir um elemento semântico mais específico para representá-lo.

***Notas de uso***

- Cada `<section>` deve ser identificado, geralmente incluindo um cabeçalho (elemento `<h1>-<h6>`) como um filho do elemento `<section>`.
- Se faz sentido distribuir separadamente o conteúdo de um elemento , use um elemento `<article>` em seu lugar.
- Não use o elemento `<section>` como um *container* genérico; para isso que a `<div>` serve, especialmente quando a seção é apenas com propósito de estilização. Uma regra de ouro é quando um seção deve aparecer logicamente na estrutura de um documento.

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section

Vc pode usar uma section para definir áreas ou regiões para:

Textos introdutórios
Listagens
Mapas
Comentários
Informações de contato
Etc...

---

**ARTICLE**

O Elemento HTML Article (`<article>`) representa uma composição independente em um documento, página, aplicação, ou site, ou que é destinado a ser distribuído de forma independente ou reutilizável, por exemplo, em sindicação. Este poderia ser o post de um fórum, um artigo de revista ou jornal, um post de um blog, um comentário enviado por um usuário, um *gadget* ou *widget* interativos, ou qualquer outra forma de conteúdo independente.

***Notas de uso***

- Quando um elemento `<article>` está aninhado, o elemento interior representa um artigo relacionado com o elemento exterior. Por exemplo, os comentários do post de um blog podem ser elementos `<article>` aninhados em `<article>` representando o post do blog.
- Informações sobre o autor de um elemento `<article>` podem ser fornecidas através do elemento `<address>`, mas ele não se aplica aos elementos `<article>` aninhados.
- A data e hora de publicação de um elemento `<article>` pode ser descrita usando o atributo *pubdate* de um elemento `<time>`.

Normalmente se usa um `heading` dentro do `article` e tb pode ser aconselhável usar um `footer` também.

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article

Vc pode usar uma section para definir áreas ou regiões para:

Poste em Foruns
Entradas de Blog
Artigos
Etc..

O que se observa é que vc pode separa por exemplo um conjunto de `articles` em uma `section`, e em cada um desses `articles` vc pode ter outras `sections` dentro. Por isso acredito que vc ficou um pouco confuso. Diferente do elemento `<main>` por exemplo, que não é aconselhável ter mais de um por documento, ou defini-lo dentro de um `article`. *[Fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main)*

**Modelo de estrutura construída com tags semânticas:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo de "estrutura não semântica" versos "estrutura semântica"**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Fonte:* https://www.vikingcodeschool.com/html5-and-css3/html5-semantic-tags

**OBS:** Segundo esse artigo sobre ***Estruturas Semânticas*** e Acessibilidade da Mozilla

> Atualmente não há implementações conhecidas do algorítmo de estrutura em navegadores gráficos ou `user agents` de tecnologia assistiva, apesar disso o algorítmo é implementado em outro software como em verificadores de conformidade. Assim, ao algorítmo de estrutura não pode ser confiada a  entrega da estrutura do documento para os usuários. Autores são aconselhados a usar níveis de cabeçalho (h1-h6) para transmitir a estrutura do documento.

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document

*Artigo que recomendo a leitura:* https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/semantic-html/

---

**Exemplo prático**

Nesse exemplo vai ficar a critério do time definir o escopo e entendimento de como deve ser interpretado semanticamente "Missão, Visão e Valores". Se cada parte funciona sozinha ou se a mensagem só funciona em conjunto.

Se vc entende que a "Missão, Visão e Valores" pertencem ao mesmo contexto, e não faria sentido, por exemplo, usar apenas os *Valores* de forma insolada em outras partes do site, te sugiro usar um `article` montado como abaixo:

```html
<article>
  <h2>Missão, Visão e Valores</h2>
  <section>
    <h3>Missão</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Visão</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Valores</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

Já se vc acredita que é plenamente possível usar apenas a Missão em determinada parte da página e que mesmo insolada ela passaria a mensagem de forma adequada e não depende de *Visão* e *Valores* vc pode separar "Missão, Visão e Valores" em `articles` dentro de uma `section`, pois o `article` funciona de forma independente sem depender do restante do conteúdo ao redor.

```html
<section>
  <h2>Missão, Visão e Valores</h2>
  <article>
    <h3>Missão</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h3>Visão</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h3>Valores</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Muito boa a reposta, só pra ver se eu entendi... Estou atualizando um site estático de página única baseada em `<div>`, nele há alguns `<article>`, como "Quem somos", "Missão, visão e valores" e "Contato", no segundo há 3 `<section>` ("Missão", "Visão" e "Valores"), estou certo?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam veja que vc pode ter uma Section com um H2 chamado "Missão Visão e Valores" e dentro dessa Section vc pode ter um Article para H3 Missão, um Article para H3 Visão, etc... Eu acredito que vc pode usar por exemplo só o Article H3 Valores, em outras parte do site, sem precisar da Visão e Missão por exemplo. Então eu vejo esse conteúdo como independente. Mas se vc julgar que eles são "inseparáveis" Ai seria melhor começar com um Article, e dentro dele fazer uma Section para cada Missão, Visão e Valores, já que eles podem não fazer sentido pra vc se usados separados.

Comment: Pessoalmente, não vejo sentido em qualquer um dos três isolados, sem os outros dois, não que fique incompreensível, mas diminui bastante o seu significado, por isso o uso do `<section>`. No caso, cada um dos três, com um título e um parágrafo, sem um título pai "Missão Visão e Valores", como os três juntos podem estar separados do restante do conteúdo sem perder  o sentido, imaginei colocar em um `<article>`. Valeu pela ajuda, no final o uso de cada um é um pouco subjetivo, já que vai da interpretação de cada um o quão dependente aquele elemento é de seu contexto

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam exato, esse é um caso um pouco mais particular... Repare no *Exemplo Prático* que acabei de colocar na edição da minha resposta. Abordo justamente isso

Comment: Uma última dúvida, o `article` deve independente dos outros elementos da página ou do contexto que ele está (`aside`, `main`, `section` ou outro `article`)? Porque no caso da segunda opção "Missão", "Visão" e "Valores" seriam `article` dentro de `article` (seguindo a ideia do seu primeiro exemplo prático)

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam teoricamente vc pode ter um article como filho de outro article, mas eu acredito que mesmo vc podendo nesse caso vc não deveria... Se vc disse e pretende usa-lo como um "bloco único" não há pq ter outros articles dentro. No seu caso eu sugiro vc usar o primeiro exemplo, article > sections com missão visão valores, já que não vai separa-las e sempre estarão dentro do mesmo article.

Comment: Ok, então o `article` deve ser independente dos outros elementos da página (`body`) e não do contexto em que está, né?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam o que eu quero dizer é que vc tb tem que ter uma coerência com seu conteúdo. Vc não deve usar o conteúdo em um lugar como article e depois usa-lo em outro momento como uma section. Nav Main Aside etc cada um tem sua função e suas particularidades vc pode usar um article com Missão etc... Dentro do Main e depois repetir esse Article com Missão etc... em um Aside. Vc só não deve usa-lo cada hora de um jeito, ou construir ele como article e depois querer fragmentar os pedaços dele em sections no footer por exemplo. O Body faz parte da estrutura do  documento não do conteúdo

Answer (score 5):

Ambas servem para marcar blocos de código, para simplesmente separar as coisas, ou para usar uma formatação diferenciada.

Antes do `HTML5`, só havia a tag `div` com esse propósito mais genérico de separar as coisas, então tudo era separado no layout por divs, menus, navegação, seções de links, rodapés, headers, etc.

O `HTML5` introduziu tags **semânticas**, ou seja, que tem mais uma funções pra ajudar no entendimento e interpretação do layout do que propriamente uma função de design, como `table` e `h1` por exemplo.

Tags como `header`, `footer`, `section` e `article` tem essa função: marcar o que é cada coisa em separado no layout do `html`. Quando você olha uma estrutura assim:

```
<header>
   <nav>
   </nav>
</header>
<section>
</section>
<section>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Você facilmente identifica que há um cabeçalho com uma barra de navegação nele, duas sessões distintas, e no final um rodapé.
Isso poderia ser feito somente com `div`, mas imagina a confusão que seria para identificar rapidamente o que faz cada parte no layout?

Por isso a semântica é importante, as tags não tem um comportamento especial, mas marcam bem como é o layout, daí a diferença enter usar um `section` por exemplo e simplesmente um `div`.

Aproveitando, uma ótima leitura sobre semântica do Anderson Carlos Woss:   [O que é esboço HTML (HTML Outlines)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/247289/5878)

**EDIT** para responder o comentário, vou usar as definições do mozilla:

### ARTICLE: [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)

> O Elemento HTML Article (`<article>`) representa uma composição
>   independente em um documento, página, aplicação, ou site, ou que é
>   destinado a ser distribuido de forma independente ou reutilizável, por
>   exemplo, em sindicação. Este poderia ser o post de um fórum, um artigo
>   de revista ou jornal, um post de um blog, um comentário enviado por um
>   usuário, um gadget ou widget interativos, ou qualquer outra forma de
>   conteúdo independente.

### SECTION: [section](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)

> O elemento HTML `<section>` representa uma seção genérica contida em
>   um documento HTML, geralmente com um título, quando não existir um
>   elemento semântico mais específico para representá-lo.
>
> Por exemplo, um menu de navegação deve estar dentro um elemento
>   `<nav>`, mas uma lista de resultados de pesquisa ou a exibição de um
>   mapa e seus controles não possuem elementos específicos, e podem ser
>   colocados dentro de uma `<section>`.

O site [tableless.com.br](http://tableless.com.br/sections-html5/) traz uma definição simplificada mas interessante:

> **ARTICLE** Define a área onde há um artigo, texto, redação, conteúdo e etc…
>
> **SECTION** Define um bloco ou um grupo de um assunto específico. É importante entender que a section agrupa diversos elementos que tenham
>   relação entre si. Por exemplo, se há uma área no site que há links,
>   conteúdo, imagens e etc de um assunto em comum, você agrupará esses
>   elementos com uma section. Nesse caso, ele entrou no lugar daquele div
>   que fazíamos para dividir grandes blocos de assuntos em comum.

Comment: Sobre esta semântica que citou, eu falei um pouco em [O que é esboço HTML (HTML Outlines)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/247289/5878) Provavelmente será de interesse para quem ler sua resposta.

Comment: muito bom mesmo @AndersonCarlosWoss, inclui na resposta!

Comment: Tá mas qual a diferença entre `section` e `article`? Entendo a questão do que é a semântica, e significado de outras tags, por exemplo,`header`, `footer` e `aside`. A dúvida é exclusivamente entre o uso e significado do `section` e `article`, em que situação usar um ou outro?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam, adicionei ao texto da pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Sim, tanto o `<section>` como o `<article>` parecem que são a mesma coisa e que tanto faz usar um ou outro, mas não é bem assim.

**Resumo:** `<section>` por sí só não tem um significado, já `<article>` deve ser usado para representar elementos que são independentes e auto-explicativos.

•**section**: A especificação diz que ele é um bloco de conteúdo semânticamente genérico, ou seja: ele não tem um significado explícito e você deveria usar ele caso não houver outros elementos mais semânticos que melhor descrevem o conteúdo em questão. A ponto chave aqui é que, o que vai dar o significado para o `<section>` é um título que está dentro dele (valores do atributo role também).
**Ex.:**

```html
<section>
    <h2>Comentários da página</h2>
</section>
```

Nesse caso, o título está dando significado a aquela `<section>`. Vale deixar bem claro também que, se por acaso na `<section>` que você estiver usando não tiver um título dentro dela, muito possivelmente isso quer dizer que você está usando a `<section>` de forma errada, e seria mais apropriado por exemplo utilizar um `<div>`.
**Ex.:**

```html
<section>
  <button>curtir</button>
  <button>não curtir</button>
  <button>salvar</button>
</section>
```

Nesse caso até que está correto (pois nenhum elemento mais semântico poderia ser usado aqui), mas seria mais apropriado usar `<div>`, principalmente se você quer apenas utilizar o elemento apenas para estilizar, onde se você apenas quer utilizar um wrapper para estilizar em hipótese alguma você usa `<section>`.

•**article**: Ele basicamente é um elemento independente, que não possui relação direta com o restante da página e que mesmo se o seu conteúdo fosse tratado de forma independente ele continuaria fazendo sentido, pois o seu conteúdo não possui relação direita com a pagina. Ele é ideal para ser usado por exemplo para envolver o conteúdo dentro de um artigo (já que ele é independente do resto da página), tanto como os comentários da página (já que eles são independentes e podem reutilizados separadamente), ou até um card de um produto, uma propaganda, um card de um vídeo também (vídeos do YouTube)... E por aí vai. Nesse caso também é legal ter um título dentro do , mas não é obrigatório. Caso você tenha um `<article>` dentro de um outro `<article>` implica dizer que o elemento aninhado possui uma relação direta com o seu `<article>` pai, sendo isso útil para envolver semânticamente os comentários de um artigo.
**Ex.:**

```html
<article>
  <header>
     <h1>Como Ter dinheiro</h1>
     <p>Henrique Barbosa</p>
  </header>
  <p>Basta ser rico KKK</p>

   <section>
     <h2>Comentários</h2>
     
     <article id="comment-1">
        <header>
          <p>Adriano Gomes</p>
        </header>
        <p>Mds cara esse artigo foi uma merdaKKKKKK</p>
     </article>
   </section>
</article>
```

**OBS**: Perceba que o `<article>` principal representa o artigo como um todo, e os artigos dentro dele representa os comentários, pois os comentários possuem uma relação direta com o artigo. 
**OBS2**: Se você olhar bem, dentro de cada `<article>` tem um `<header>`. Esse header basicamente serve para dar mais informações sobre o `<article>`. Você poderia usar um `<footer>` também. 
**OBS3**: Perceba também que eu usei um `</section>` dentro do `<article>`. Isso é normal, pois como eu disse:

> ele é um bloco de conteúdo semânticamente genérico

Ou seja, você dá o significado que você quiser pra ele, especialmente nesse caso aqui que eu deixei claro que ele representa a seção de comentários do artigo.
Também é permitido usar um adress dentro do article para dizer onde você pode encontrar o autor daquele artigo, mas colocar o adress dentro de um article que está aninhado dentro de outro article não funciona.